# HTML5 Bluetooth and Audio

Tags: audio, html, bluetooth

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#bluetooth-broadcast) mentions Bluetooth and audio. But no details on Bluetooth.

I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth device that streams audio.

Is there anyway to capture the audio streams via Bluetooth on browser? HTML+Javascript? Plug-ins? Any other technique?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about streaming audio *to* a bluetooth device, or *from* a bluetooth device?

Comment: From a bluetooth device to the browser.

Answer (score 8):

The link that you've referred to is an old draft of the specification, and it's not included in the current version of the HTML5 draft.

[HTML5 Device API Requirements](http://www.w3.org/TR/dap-api-reqs/) specifies about interfaces that can get the information of the available network interfaces and provides no way to control them.

So you cannot use HTML5 to connect to a Bluetooth device that streams audio.

You might be able to achieve this by writing your own ActiveX Component (works only in IE) or an Applet.

You'll need desktop application to connect and stream data through Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop versions of Google Chrome now have a Chrome Bluetooth API, so it is now possible to connect to Bluetooth devices from a web page using Google Chrome:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth

There is also a web API for Bluetooth, at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API, however only chrome uses it, and is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `MediaStream` API that allows you access to any video and audio streaming device that the user has connected. You can checkout the specs [here](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#stream-api).