# Access Bluetooth device from PC using HTML5

Tags: android, html, web, bluetooth

Is it possible to write an android application that communicates with the HTML5 code on a PC browser, via Bluetooth ? 
Are there any HTML5 libraries that lets you access Bluetooth functionalities in the system (PC) ?

Comment: HTML5 has no concept of transport - be it LAN, WLAN or Bluetooth. It relies on the underlying OS to care for that. A browser plugin might or might not be able to fix that, but not in a cross-platform (or cross-version) way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063277/html5-bluetooth-and-audio