# Sending information through bluetooth using Javascript

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, chrome-dev-editor

I'm planning on making an HTML5 Chrome App where users will be able to connect to each other using bluetooth and they will be able to send messages. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap can do this for hybrid apps: https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth

Otherwise it appears that the ability to use Bluetooth from HTML5 was removed from the spec. For more information, see this other question: [HTML5 Bluetooth and Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063277/html5-bluetooth-and-audio)

Comment: See that's the issue. I'm using a chromebook and I cannot get PhoneGab on it.